# text class and main class in Semantic UI?

Tags: html, frontend, semantic-ui

I'm still new to frontend, and I following a tutorial and write my own code to learn to use Semantic UI's `Segment` to create a table of blog. From the first line of the code below, 
 I noticed ".text" class makes the width of the segment narrower.  However, I couldn't find the explanation of ".text".  Could someone point me to the right direction?

```
<div class="ui main text container">
  <div class="ui segment">

    <div class="ui divided items">
      <% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="<%= blog.image %>">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <a class="header"href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>"><%=blog.title%></a>
          <div class="description">
            <p><%= blog.body %></p>
          </div>
          <div class="extra">
            <form action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>">
              <input type="submit" value="Read More" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% }) %>
    </div>

  </div>

</div> <!-- /End of container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `text` or `main` class in semantic, if you are wanting to style text you just need to place it in `p` tags as mentioned on this page https://semantic-ui.com/globals/site.html